# efficient way for save many relatively large files

Tags: database, repository, bigdata, large-files

i am working on a downloader project that crawl on web (some pages) and download video files.

I'm looking for a solution(Selecting proper database) that can save downloaded videos with fast search and scalable storage features.

At the beginning i guessed that MS SQL Server with FILE-STREAM enabled can be good option.

Is there better way for managing videos.